# SQL 2014 Query runs much faster in sp_executesql than as plain query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

Very strange issue, I have looked but best I can see this is not a known issue.

I am debugging a query that someone else wrote for a SSRS report.

When run from SSRS returns 13,730 rows. I captured this query execution in SQL Profiler then ran it in SSMS which returned 11,940 rows.  The report does nothing with the result set, it just shows each row.

I then took the query out of sp_executesql and converted the sp_executesql params into normal params. When this is run in SSMS the query just endlessly spins with a CXPACKET wait type.

I don't understand how essentially the same query can have such vastly different results and execution plans by way of running it.

I can't copy the whole query here, but the gist of it is:

```
/* Example 1 

    This returns different results when run from the report (SQL Server Reporting Services 2014) as opposed to when run in SQL Server Management Studio. The actual execution from SSRS was captured using profiler

    Either execution completed in about 15 seconds.

*/

exec sp_executesql N'

CREATE TABLE #tmpTable (
    field1 varchar(250),
    field2 int,
    field3 varchar(max)
)

Insert into #tmpTablea
    SELECT
        somestuff as field1,
        someotherstuff as field2,
        morestuff as field3
    FROM
        RealTable
    WHERE
        somestuff = ''stuff that matters for the first query''
    AND
        otherstuff = @param1


Insert into #tmpTable
    SELECT
        somestuff as field1,
        someotherstuff as field2,
        morestuff as field3
    FROM
        RealTable2
    WHERE
        somestuff = ''stuff that matters for the second query''
    AND
        otherstuff = @param2

    SELECT * FROM #tmpTable

    ',N'@param1 nvarchar(4000),@param2 nvarchar(4000)',@param1=N'value1',@param2=N'value2'


/* Example 2 

    This one just runs forever, I cancelled it after 15 minutes.

*/

Declare @param1 nvarchar(4000),
        @param2 nvarchar(4000)

SELECT @param1  = 'value1',
        @param2 = 'value2'

CREATE TABLE #tmpTable (
    field1 varchar(250),
    field2 int,
    field3 varchar(max)
)

Insert into #tmpTable
    SELECT
        somestuff as field1,
        someotherstuff as field2,
        morestuff as field3
    FROM
        RealTable
    WHERE
        somestuff = ''stuff that matters for the first query''
    AND
        otherstuff = @param1


Insert into #tmpTable
    SELECT
        somestuff as field1,
        someotherstuff as field2,
        morestuff as field3
    FROM
        RealTable2
    WHERE
        somestuff = ''stuff that matters for the second query''
    AND
        otherstuff = @param2

    SELECT * FROM #tmpTable
```

Comment: Regarding the results from the query and SSRS, Did you check the report for any 'hidden' expressions or calculations?

Comment: "Runs forever" is almost never a performance issue, it's usually blocking or some type of resource wait. Did you check `sys.dm_exec_requests` to see if the session has a `blocking_session_id` or what exactly it is waiting on?

Comment: There are no hidden expressions, there is one expression but it is merely the equivalent of an ISNULL() expression.

Comment: Nor are there any blocking session IDs. The result that gets returned from SSRS is the correct value, I have validated this with a less complex query.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting.  You may have uncovered something not published about SQL-Server's internal behavior.

You mentioned that when you run the query without sp_executesql that it spins with a CXPACKET wait type.  This means that the query optimizer parallelized your query.  CXPACKET wait type is what happens when the processes running the query are exchanging information.

When you use sp_executesql, it just runs right away, which suggests that sp_execautesql (no CXPACKET wait type) is not parallelizing your query, or not parallelizing it as much.

You can test this theory easily.  At the end of each statement in the version that is NOT using sp_executesql, put:

OPTION (MAXDOP 0);

This is effectively telling Sql-Server to use only one core, and should guarantee no CXPACKET waits.

If this helps, then test it with MAXDOP 1, MAXDOP 2, etc ...

NOTE: In general, the query optimizer does a good job of figuring out when to parallelize and the degree to do so (i.e., it figures out what the optimal MAXDOP value), but sometimes, it doesn't, and after some experimenting hints like this can speed things up.